# Что в данном случае делегирует super?

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста начинающему разработчику-самоучке с кодом.
Как в данной ситуации работает super()? **Почему мы наследуемся от класса LoginForm и какого-то объекта self?** Насколько я понял мы получаем каким-то образом данные (в виде объекта), а потом с помощью clean() получаем данные в чистом виде.

Вот весь код:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Введите Ваш логин')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Введите Ваш пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Пользователь с таким логином не зарегистрирован!')

        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if user and not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Неверный пароль!')
```

Из него непонятный строки:

```
cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
username = self.cleaned_data['username']
```

Comment: Это просто такой способ получения доступа к методам родительского класса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройдёмся по порядку:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
```

1. Форма `super(LoginForm, self)` в общем-то избыточна, обычно в этом случае используют просто `super()` - это в точности тоже самое
2. По сути мы тут получаем доступ к нашему объекту `self` класса `LoginForm`, так, как будто это объект класса-родителя, т.е. класса `forms.Form`
3. Мы и так имеем доступ к методам и полям, унаследованным от класса-предка, проблема тут возникает в случае перекрытия методов предка методами потомка с теми же названиями
4. Таким образом, нам приходится использовать `super()`, потому что и в нашем текущем класса `LoginForm` и в классе-родителе `forms.Form` есть метод `clean` и мы поэтому не можем его вызвать просто как `self.clean()` - в этом случае у нас вызовется метод потомка, который перекрыл метод родителя.

Итого - мы вызвали метод `clean` класса-родителя (передав ему экземпляр нашего класса), он что-то сделал внутри себя и вернул нам некие данные, которые мы положили в переменную `cleaned_data`.

```
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
```

А вот это смешно - мы тут же забыли про нашу переменную `cleaned_data` и вместо этого пользуемся теми данными, которые метод `clean` видимо создал в самом классе в виде поля `self.cleaned_data` (и потом видимо их ещё и вернул из метода `clean()`).

Ну, видимо, такая небрежность программиста. Неиспользуемая переменная - это нехороший признак, значит программист не совсем контролирует свои данные и не до конца понимает, что он с ними хочет делать. Если возвращаемые данные не нужны - можно их было просто не получать из метода и никуда не присваивать. Но тут они по идее нужны, а вместо готовых данных в локальной переменной он достаёт ещё раз эти данные из поля класса. Выглядит неаккуратно и запутывает читающего код, кроме того.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Вот такой ответ я и хотел получить)